# What does it mean to scale random variables?

Tags: self-study, central-limit-theorem, asymptotics, intuition

We just started learning asymptotic theory, and to prove the lindberg-levy central limit theorem, weak law of large numbers etc, we 'scale and standardize' the RVs so it ends up having a standard normal distribution when sample size T tends to $\infty$. The math behind it is straightforward but can someone give a quick intuition or an example of what it means to 'scale' a RV, by $T^{1/2}$ for example?

Comment: I think scaling results in the variable that behaves as a random variable. T1/2  ie square root of T here should  imply that we take a square-root of sample size. May be someone is trying to implement variance-stabilization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Scaling a random variable" may be used in various situations for various reasons and in various ways, but related to the Central Limit Theorem, the intuition is straightforward. Consider the quantity

$$\bar X_T-\mu$$
where $\bar X_T$ is the sample average (and as a function it depends on the sample size $T$), from an i.i.d sample, and also it is an estimator of the population mean $\mu$. Now $\bar X_T$ is a consistent estimator, meaning that as $T\rightarrow \infty$, $\bar X_T$ tends to $\mu$ in probability, or essentially, it stops being a random variable and "collapses to the constant $\mu$", and so $(\bar X_T-\mu)$ collapses to zero.

Now, if it collapses to zero, it cannot have a distribution, right? "But this is good - uncertainty is eliminated"... no it is not good, because uncertainty is eliminated at an infeasible situation -actual infinite sample size. So we need something "intermediate", we *need* our estimator to maintain the identity of a non-constant random variable, so that we are able to "describe" the structure of unavoidable uncertainty through the properties of its distribution.

So we need to do something to *prevent* $(\bar X_T-\mu)$ from collapsing to zero -but at the same time, this "something" must not be such as make $(\bar X_T-\mu)$ explode to infinity. It has been found that if we multiply the *shrinking* difference $(\bar X_T-\mu)$ by the *growing* factor $\sqrt T$ then the product $\sqrt T(\bar X_T-\mu)$ neither collapses to zero, nor it explodes to infinity as $T\rightarrow \infty$, but it remains a random variable that asymptotically has a Normal Distribution.

Comment: thank you, this is a great answer! After reading your intuition this is my understanding: In our example of the sample mean $\bar{X}_T$, the V[$\bar{X}_T] = \sigma^2/T $. So by introducing a scaling of $T^{1/2}$(growing factor) to $\bar{X}_T$ , the new variance will be just $\sigma^2$, which is now sample size independent, and has a distribution which we can observe for properties, instead of converging to a constant. I hope ive understood this right!

Comment: Yes, that's an intuitive way to justify why in this case we need to scale (multiply) by $T^{1/2}$, so that $\bar X_T$ retains a distribution. A smaller scaling would still result in the variance becoming zero, a larger scaling would result in the variance becoming infinite.